# Is there a canon outcome to the Kronus War/Dark Crusade?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war

A lot of games feature alternate storylines depending on which character/race you pick at the start, and Warhammer's *Dawn of War: Dark Crusade* is no different.

With 7 races vying for control of the planet, there is presumably 7 different outcomes to the overall storyline. The question is: *Who actually won?*. Is there canon evidence that states, say, that the Tau or the Space Marines, or any other race ultimately won the Dark Crusade and took control of the planet Kronus?

Comment: It appears that which ever team you use -- granted you beat the game -- Wins and sustains control of Kronus... I never actually thought about this when playing the game until now...

Comment: There are a few mentions of what happened on Kronus during the DoW II campaign. I don't remember it in details but in this canon it's definitely the Space Marines which destroyed the Necrons (and I suppose won the war). You could try playing it :) or search for DoW II lore.

Answer (score -1):

Yes actually there is... it goes something like as follows:
The space marines ultimately win (boring I know, but hey, the game creators love to play favorites), they destroy chaos, then orks, then tau without any problems, they then suffer heavy casualties against the eldar, and the commander ultimately defeats the necron lord, at great personal cost (he kinda gets his face chewed)

So... yeah that's something like what happened

(Look at the necromancy skills)

Comment: Do you have a source that confirms this?